# Leaflet is not working correctly in Mozilla Firefox browser when LWS is enabled in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-web-components, lws, firefox, sf, leaflet.js

In Salesforce to show the map with pointers I created custom LWC and use Leaflet.js library but there is an issue with LWS and Mozilla Firefox.

When LWS is enabled then in Mozilla Firefox browser marker popup is not being shown when I click on marker. In Chrome and Safari all works good but in Firefox it does not.

```
const marker = L.marker([lat, lon], {
  icon: myIcon,
}).addTo(this.map);

marker.bindPopup(popupContent);
```

No errors appear in console when I click on pointer.

Also only in Firefox sometimes I get an error **Lightning Web Security: Cannot access rangeParent** when I drag/move map, after page refreshing this error might disappear but after another refresh it might appear as well.

[image]

When Lightning Locker is enabled then all works good in Firefox and Chrome/Safari it still working good as it was with LWS.

Any ideas why popup is not being shown in Firefox when LWS enabled and I get this error message when drap the map?

Comment: Any updates on this issue or did you find a workaround? We are running into the same exact issue.

Comment: Can't help you @ScottAlden but I'd encourage you to open a case with Salesforce. I'm sure for them it doens't make sense to support a browser with such a low marketshare, but given it's the only one with a different rendering engine that's got any kind of share I feel it's important to let people know it's being used!